# Limit TextField Input to Capitals letters, Numbers and Character limit of 6?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, nsstring, uitextfield

I've searched online and found a lot of examples on limiting TextFields, but I can't find any on limiting multiple factors. The Code I'm working messes up the input and I cant figure out why.

Heres my code:
(Note: I have already set the delegate)

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = LPinput.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
    LPinput.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.uppercased())
    return newLength <= limitLength
}
```

Here's what I type into the TextField:

> food

And here's what is shown in the TextField:

> FfOoOoD

Please help!

Comment: What is LPinput?  Why are you returning Bool with your function?

Comment: Never return `true` from `shouldChangeCharactersIn` if you update the text field's `text` property.

Comment: @ElTomato What else would you return from a delegate method with a return type of `Bool`?

Comment: LPinput is the name of my TextField

Comment: @Dan.code you need add all the text as Uppercased? is this your main issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rmaddy says, The problem is that you are modifiying the `UITextField.text` property and returning true after that, this cause the duplicated behavior founded in your question, so I change that and first check the textLength and after that modify the text and return always false to avoid adding duplicate characters try with this code

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = LPinput.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
    if(newLength <= limitLength)
    {
    LPinput.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.uppercased())
    }
    return false
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you, Im starting to understand this now! much appreciated!